# web crawling:how to retrieve number only among text-and number combination

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler

How can I scrape the number only in this whole html. In this example, I want the output to be '7'.

```html
<div class="pagination">
    7 posts • Page <strong>1</strong> of <strong>1</strong>
</div>
```

Here's my code:

```
for num_replys in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'pagination'}):
        print(num_reply)
```

Comment: please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could use re for exmaple assuming you always have number space posts as pattern. You could possibly use split as well. You need to keep your loop variable having the same name and you want to work with it's `.text` value.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="pagination">
    7 posts • Page <strong>1</strong> of <strong>1</strong>
</div>

'''

p = re.compile(r'(\d+)\s+posts')
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')

for num_reply in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'pagination'}):
    print(int(p.findall(num_reply.text)[0]))
```